# Exception while analyzing expression at AppDatabase

Tags: kotlin, android-room

Here is my AppDatabase.kt

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Loan::class), version = 3)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun loanModel(): LoanDao

    companion object {
        private const val DB_NAME = "loans.db"

        fun createPersistentDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase
                = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME).build()
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
 e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Exception while analyzing expression at (11,54) in /Users/mladenrakonjac/MyFirstKotlinApp/app/src/main/java/me/mnemonic/myloan/data/AppDatabase.kt:
3

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.logOrThrowException(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:250)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.lambda$getTypeInfo$0(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.PerformanceCounter.time(PerformanceCounter.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingVisitorDispatcher.java:142)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.expressions.ExpressionTypingServices.getTypeInfo(ExpressionTypingServices.java:121)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.ArgumentTypeResolver.getArgumentTypeInfo(ArgumentTypeResolver.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.ArgumentTypeResolver.analyzeArgumentsAndRecordTypes(ArgumentTypeResolver.java:379)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.doResolveCall(CallResolver.java:600)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.doResolveCallOrGetCachedResults(CallResolver.java:529)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.lambda$computeTasksFromCandidatesAndResolvedCall$1(CallResolver.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.PerformanceCounter.time(PerformanceCounter.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.computeTasksFromCandidatesAndResolvedCall(CallResolver.java:206)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.computeTasksFromCandidatesAndResolvedCall(CallResolver.java:196)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.resolveConstructorCall(CallResolver.java:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.resolveCallForConstructor(CallResolver.java:350)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.resolveFunctionCall(CallResolver.java:282)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.calls.CallResolver.resolveFunctionCall(CallResolver.java:253)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.AnnotationResolverImpl.resolveAnnotationCall(AnnotationResolverImpl.java:151)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyAnnotationDescriptor.computeValueArguments(LazyAnnotations.kt:143)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyAnnotationDescriptor.access$computeValueArguments(LazyAnnotations.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyAnnotationDescriptor$valueArguments$1.invoke(LazyAnnotations.kt:126)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyAnnotationDescriptor$valueArguments$1.invoke(LazyAnnotations.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:323)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:364)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyAnnotationDescriptor.getAllValueArguments(LazyAnnotations.kt:140)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyAnnotationDescriptor.forceResolveAllContents(LazyAnnotations.kt:161)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.resolveMemberHeaders(LazyClassDescriptor.java:535)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.doForceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:521)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.lambda$new$4(LazyClassDescriptor.java:220)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:323)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.forceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:517)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:66)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:34)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:119)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:133)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doAnalysis(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.doAnalysis(Kapt3Extension.kt:145)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:97)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:139)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.compileChanged(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:443)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:301)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:128)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:452)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$$special$$inlined$withIC$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:379)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$$special$$inlined$withIC$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:798)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:825)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:797)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:865)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:791)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:378)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:865)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:336)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Answer (score 2):

The last line of that log says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

If your computer has a reasonable amount of RAM, you should file a bug report with JetBrains.

This question has lots of good information on that error: [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)